Automating F-Curve changes in Blender/Python to Match Song
I have a visualizer in Blender that can visualize songs. While I can change the songs using a script, I'm struggling to adjust the visualizer's f-curves to match the dynamics of the new songs. This process is being handled headlessly on a console with the following command:
blender -b "path\blender.blend" -P "path\python.py"

In the script, I successfully change the song in the video sequencer and render the final output. However, I'm unable to figure out how to modify the f-curves accordingly. How can I programmatically adjust the f-curves in Blender to the new song?
